# Insert some data of a datagridview at once to Access database

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2016

I'm new in C# and i would like to insert some Datagridview columns to Access in order to retrieve this data afterwards.

```cs
private void metroButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
try
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = F:\Database\DBAdatabase.accdb; Persist Security Info = False; ");
    for (int s = 0; s < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; s++)

    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Quotations (Position, LVPosition)VALUES('"+dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[0].Value+"','"+dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[1].Value+"')", connection);

        connection.Open();

        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

        connection.Close();
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error   " + ex);
}
```

I become the Error Systen.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntaxerror in the Insert Into.

Can somebody help me to solve it .....

Thx a lot..

I also referred to the this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hCfje5VL-0&ab_channel=codefactory2016), but I cant find what's the error reason.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Off the bat, I would change

```
MessageBox.Show("Error   " + ex);
```

to

```
MessageBox.Show("Error   " + ex.Message);
```

It will give you a better understanding of the error

Also, it is very good practice to use parameters, this prevents single quote issues and prevents sql injection problems:

```
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = F:\Database\DBAdatabase.accdb; Persist Security Info = False; ");
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("", connection);
            for (int s = 0; s < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; s++)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position",dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[0].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lvPosition",dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[1].Value);

                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Quotations (Position, LVPosition) VALUES (@position, @lvPosition)";

                connection.Open();

                //this line is not needed as it is set in the command constructor above
                //command.Connection = connection; 

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

                connection.Close();

                //edit - this needs to run or you will have duplicate values inserted
                command.Parameters.Clear(); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error   " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Even still I would seriously look into using statements for the connection and command, and have a try catch around opening the connection. But that is getting a bit off topic

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I still have the same Insert Into error .

Comment: Are the values text or numeric? Are the field names correct?

Comment: The "Position"  is a autonumber column in the Datagridview and a short Text in access.he "LVPostion" a text value. I checked the field names and they are correct

Comment: Okay, then use the parameters, as you have your position field in single quotes indicating text, not a number.
Or you can just remove the single quotes from your first value field

Comment: I changed the access field name, so not to be equal as the datagridview column name and it WORKS!!!! Thank you so much

Comment: Although it takes only the values of the first Datagridview row and copy it so much times as the number of datagridview rows. Why does it transfer to access only the first row?

Comment: Ugh, just figured this out, the parameters are not being cleared. You must type command.Parameters.Clear(); after connection.Close(); I have edited the post